# github: transfer ownership and fork

Tags: github, git-fork

I've transfered ownership of one of my github repositories (rdmuller/docToolchain) to an organisation (docToolchain/docToolchain).
So far, so good. All old URLs are redirected to the new location. Perfect.

But how do I now fork this repository? I fear that, if I fork it, a fork with the name of the old repository (rdmueller/docToolchain) will be created and the redirect will be broken this way...

how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I guess I found a workaround.

suppose you have a repository

`user1/repo1`

You now want to transfer ownership to `org1` and create a fork of it in your account `user1`.

The problem is that, if you create this fork directly, there will be again a repo called `user1/repo1` and github is not able to redirect URLs to the old repository to `org1/repo1`

Solution:

- transfer ownership from `user1/repo1` to `org1/repo1`
- create a temporary organisation `org2`
- fork `org1/repo1` to `org2/repo1`
- rename `org2/repo1` to something like `org2/repo1-fork`
- transfer ownership from `org2/repo1-fork` to `user1/repo1-fork`

this seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Since May 2020, [Ben Balter](https://twitter.com/benbalter) (Senior Product Manager working on Community and Safety at @GitHub) mentions in [his tweet](https://twitter.com/benbalter/status/1258832842857029633):

> We're beta testing a new GitHub feature that allows you to invite someone to manage your open source projects in the event that you are unable able to do so yourself.
>
> If you'd like early access, reply or DM with your GitHub handle and I can add you.

See "[Maintaining ownership continuity of your user account's repositories](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/maintaining-ownership-continuity-of-your-user-accounts-repositories)"

> You can invite someone to manage your user owned repositories if you are not able to.
>
> We recommend inviting another GitHub user to be your successor, to manage your user owned repositories if you cannot. As a successor, they will have permission to:
>
> - Archive your public repositories.
> - Transfer your public repositories to their own user owned account.
> - Transfer your public repositories to an organization where they can create repositories.